# Is there any single nama of devi recommended by scriptures for japa while eating?

Tags: scripture, food, bath, garga-samhita

Scriptures recommend names to recite based on the task we are doing.

For suppose, during bathing, the name Gomati is recommended

> A person who, as he bathes, says the word “Gomati" attains the pious
> result of bathing in the Gomati. Of this there is no doubt.
>
> [[9, 10, 6, Garga Samhitha]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php/GS_6.10:_In_the_Description_of_the_Gomati_River,_the_Glories_of_Cakra-tirtha)

Similarly, I am in need of a name of devi that can be recited internally while eating.

Is there any scripture that recommends a single name of devi to recite?

Comment: For ShriHari Janardana is recommended